# Programmatic property access

Tags: actionscript-3, properties

I'm programming a package that has several classes used to create generative graphics. The appearance of the generated objects is governed by getters/setters, and the graphics are retrieved by calling a 'getData' method, which returns a representation of the object in the form of a `Vector.<IGraphicsData>`.

I would like to create a class, LinkedGenerator which can control several copies of a specified generator type simultaneously. The class, for example, could be told to control several copies of the CircleGenerator class. The LinkedGenerator would have a property holding the number of CircleGenerator representations it would control, so appearance of each copy could be handled with a method which would map out the values of one of the appearance properties across the total number of copies - we could have a function like this:

```
function color(currInstance:int):uint {
    return (0xff0000 * currInstance / linkedGen.numInstances);
}
```

and then iterate over the number of copies and get the representation as follows:

```
var graphicsRep:Vector.<IGraphicsData> = new Vector.<IGraphicsData>();
for(var i:int = 0; i < linkedGen.numInstances; ++i) {
    circGen.color = color(i);
    graphicsRep = graphicsRep.concat( circGen.getData() );
}
//now pass graphicsRep to the object where it will be drawn
```

This creates a bit of a problem, however, with my method of controlling the appearance of the instanced generators - I can't guarantee which getters/setters are available to the LinkedGenerator without hard-coding the generator type to be hosted, but need to have some method of controlling them. Is there a better method of accomplishing this than the one I have supplied here? Is there a way to ensure a property exists in a class, and have a variable corresponding to the specified property (an array of the properties, for instance, so I could set color like `propertyArray[colorPropertyIndex] = newValue`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't rewrite them to all implement the same interface, wrap them all in something that implements the same interface. Then the controller will call the wrapper, and each wrapper will know how to access each wrappee.

Comment: That'd be a bit clumsy, but it's definitely work until I can reason a better solution... Are you aware of any extra overhead this would add over methods that AREN'T defined by an interface?

Comment: Hm, I've never heard of working to an interface defined as "clumsy" before. If you define something as an Interface, you don't need to care about what the inheritance chain is or compile the actual implementation into the Client Class. You'll wind up having to write a bunch of repeating code to do the different wrappers, but that's the price of freeing the implementation from the contract. Ask the Googles about the Adapter pattern or Bridge Pattern.

Comment: I say clumsy because an interface that encompassed ALL the functionality of EACH TYPE of generator would require many methods, and not all of them would be used by each generator (in some cases only half of the methods defined). I'll definitely look into those patterns - I program by hobby, not by training, so I'm always looking for new knowledge :)

Comment: I just read through those patterns - they will work PERFECTLY. Thank you! I don't have formal programming training, but I am formally trained in mathematics - these sorts of abstractions work very well with my mindset. If you are aware of any websites that compile abstract solutions like these (besides Wikipedia), I would be grateful if you'd pass them my way...

Comment: You may want to get the Head First Design Patterns Book or ActionScript 3 Design patterns (they have a website, as3dp.com, but I have gotten malware alerts going there, so go at your own risk).